# How to get dict from json one line dict

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a json file with a dict and I want to get that dict. I tried json.load(), but there comes this error message: 'json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)'
I saw this method on many websites.
My json file looks like that: (That's only an example, because I don't want to show my code)

```
{"A": 4, "B": 12}
```

And my python looks like that:

```
import json

with open("file.json", "r+") as f:
    d = json.load(f)
```

Can you please help me? (I'm using Python 3.7)

Comment: Why do you use `load(j)` and not `load(f)`?

Comment: oh i just copied that one line sorry

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check your line endings.
They need to be LF (ending with `\n`). This may cause issues sometimes.

Comment: In the json? I saw that on many websites too, but I thought I can do it like that too.

Comment: You can copy and paste your json into one of the many json validator websites available online to make sure the json you're using is valid. Then make sure to save them with the proper line endings depending on your operating system.

Comment: The JSON spec has no such line ending requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You are reading the file into `f` and trying to load `j` (which is not even specified)

Try the following code:

```
with open("test.json", "r+") as j:
    d = json.load(j)

print(d)
{'A': 4, 'B': 12}
```

Comment: yes sorry I fixed just that (I copied one line from my code)

Answer (score -1):

You need quotes around the values, so instead of

```
{"A": 4, "B": 12}
```

it needs to be

```
{"A": "4", "B": "12"}
```

Comment: Numbers in JSON objects don't need to be quoted.  If they are, then they are treated as strings not numbers.

Comment: That is actually valid JSON.  From http://json.org/: `A value can be a string in double quotes, or a number, or true or false or null, or an object or an array.`

Comment: @rockethazmat Thank you I did not know this! learn something new every day haha. I see you answer below and it makes sense, thanks for correcting me!

Answer (score -1):

Here is one line code: `d = json.load(open('test.json'))`